# How to plot heatmap of 3 variables (depth, time, parameter)

Tags: python, matlab, plot, 2d, heatmap

I have temperature data which varies with time and depth (see attached example picture). My actual data set is lot bigger though. I was wondering how can I plot a heatmap. I am open to either Python or Matlab.

Thanks.

[image: Data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In MATLAB

Below is an approach that uses the `meshgrid()` function to create a domain for the `Temperature` to be plotted on/against. To plot a 2D heat-map we can use `surf()` and set the elevation to a top view (90 degrees) by using the `view()` function. Depending if you wish to have interpolation or not the use of `shading interp` can be included or removed. To get the time labels we can convert the `Time_Vector` to a string array and use an `arrayfunc()` (array function) to replace the dot, `.` with a colon, `:`. Lastly we can use the `set()` function on the current axis, `gca` to display the newly formatted time labels on the plot. The `colormap()` can be set to a variety of options such as `'hot'`, `'winter'`, `'spring'`, etc.

[image: Heatmap Variations]

```
Time_Vector = (10.00: 0.01: 10.09);
Depth_Vector = (1:3);
Temperature = [15 16 17 18 19 20 20 20 20 20;
               25 30 35 40 45 50 50 50 50 50;
               30 35 40 45 50 55 60 65 70 75];

[Time_Grid,Depth_Grid] = meshgrid(Time_Vector,Depth_Vector);

surf(Time_Grid,Depth_Grid,Temperature);
title("Heatmap");
xlabel("Time"); ylabel("Depth");
colormap(hot);
shading interp
Angle = 0; Elevation = 90;
view(Angle,Elevation);
colorbar;

%Time label adjustments%
Time_Labels = string(Time_Vector);
Time_Labels = arrayfun(@(x) replace(x,".",":"),Time_Labels);
set(gca,'xtick',Time_Vector,'xticklabel',Time_Labels);
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: Thanks MichaelTr7. I wanted to also ask, my temperature varies from 70 to 100. However, the color spectrum change is not that profound because i guess it is considering 0-100 for example for Red to Violet change. How do you get the full color spectrum within say 70-100?

Comment: You wish to have a colour range that is normalized to data ranging from 70 to 100?

Answer (score 1):

In python, if you have your data in a matrix form, like your table, you can use the matplotlib imshow function. The downside is that the tick labels will be the position in the lists, so you need to use the FuncFormatter option to pass a function to convert the list position in the data values. One example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator, AutoLocator, FuncFormatter


#Just creating a sample data
dep = np.array([1,2,3])
time = np.arange(0,101)
dp,tm = np.meshgrid(dep,time)

matrix = np.flip(600*np.exp(-tm*dep/50),axis = 0)
#in this case we will have 3 columns, one for each depth

#ploting:
fig,ax = plt.subplots()

img = ax.imshow(matrix,cmap = 'OrRd',vmin = 0,vmax = 600,aspect = 'auto')

#set color bar
fig.colorbar(img,label = 'Temperature')

#Now we will correct the the x axis tick labels
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda *x: x[0]+1))
#And fix the positions if you dont want tick labels like 2.5 wich are not in the data
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator([0,1,2]))

ax.set_xlabel('Deph')

#correct the y axis tick labels
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda *x: '%i'%(time[-1] - x[0])))
ax.set_ylabel('Time')

plt.show()
```

[image]